# How and where to configure DSE Opscenter heap size and any other JVM parameters

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am getting OutOfMemory error on OpsCenter.log.
As per DSE documentation default heap size is 2048m (2GB), which should be enough for most installations but If I need to increase or decrease this value so where I need to change. Is there any configuration file? or need to configure in OpsCenter.conf? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My installation has the opscenter executable located at `/usr/share/opscenter/bin/opscenter`. The OPSC_JVM_OPTS variable can be set in there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the environmental variable OPSC_JVM_OPTS.
The option you need to look at is Xmx (Maximum Heap Space)

Tarball Installation:

```
$ export OPSC_JVM_OPTS=-Xmx2048m
$ sudo service opscenterd restart
```

Package Installation:

```
$ OPSC_JVM_OPTS="-server Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -Dpython.cachedir.skip=false
 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=$OPSC_LOG_PATH
 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
 -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
 -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1M -Xloggc:$OPSC_LOG_PATH/gc.log
 $OPSC_JVM_OPTS"
$ sudo service opscenterd restart
```

The documentation for configuring the OpsCenter JVM is [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.1/opsc/configure/opscJVMTuning.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not talking about cassandra jvm parameters but expecting Opscenter specific jvm parameters configurations.

Comment: Thanks Foxhound, I knew from the documentation. Can you specify the file name where I need to put these configurations for both Tarball and Package installation.

Comment: It's not a name, but an environment variable, if you just run those commands (modifying the values, it should work.)